# Core data matched date in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using `UITextField` date picker to save date in `Core Data`.

On date picker sender i got the date in this format: `2017-04-02 14:56:41`.

I want to convert it to this format `02 April 2017`.

How can i do it? Below is my code:

```
     var scheduledPickDate: NSDate!

      @IBAction func scheduleDateTextFieldBeginEditing(_ sender: UITextField) {

            let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

            datePickerView.minimumDate = NSDate() as Date

            datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date

            sender.inputView = datePickerView

            datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(WalkIn.ScheduledDateChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        }

      func ScheduledDateChanged(sender:UIDatePicker){


            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

            dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.long

            dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none

            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMMM yyyy"

             //print(sender.date)

            scheduledPickDate = scheduledPickDate as NSDate!

            //print(scheduledPickDate)


            scheduledDateWalkinPatient.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

        }

// on save function 

 managedObj.setValue(scheduledPickDate, forKey: "dateSchedule") // 2017-04-02 14:56:41
```

How can I convert var `scheduledPickDate` into this format `02 April 2017`?

Comment: The code in `ScheduledDateChanged` appears to do what you want. What issue are you having? Also note that you should only set either `dateFormat` or the two `xxxStyle`, not both.

Answer (score 1):

You're already formatting the date with:

```
dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
```

You just can't store in Coredata a date in the format you want (unless you're using a String as attribute). If then you need to retrieve that date and show it to the user, you need to format it again

Comment: so your answer suggest that i can only store a date in core data like that format 2017-04-02 14:56:41. But issue is when fetching I comapre that with current date text field. My current date format is like 02 April 2017. How can i can compare both on predicate?                                                     let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(dateSchedule >= %@ )", fromTextField.text!)

Comment: @Imran could you post a new question and paste the link here? i'll answer asap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185896/core-date-date-comparion-from-date-picker-text-field

Answer (score 0):

In core data you should store your `scheduledDate` as an `NSDate` type entity.
when you retrieve that date, you can use your `dateFormatter`. However, I would suggest using the .longStyle as dateFormat instead of "dd MMMM yyyy". It is way better for localization.