# Core Date date comparion from date picker text field

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am saving date in Core data successfully using Date type in model. Date saved in the format like 2017-04-02 14:56:41. When i retreive i want to filter date with current date text field which has a format like 02 April 2017. I am using predicate to compare both dates but app is crashed due to the difference or may be current date is in string.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(dateSchedule >= %@ )", fromTextField.text!)
```

core data date: 2017-04-02 14:56:41
currentdate textfield date: 02 April 2017

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming **dateSchedule** is a **Date** in coredata.

You can convert your text on a date variable (make sure the format is correct)

```
let dateString = "2017-04-02 14:56:41"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
```

Then you create the predicate:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(dateSchedule >= %@ )", dateObj)
```

EDIT:

If the time of the date is annoying you, you can use a utility like this one:

https://github.com/erica/SwiftDates

So you can filter with:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(dateSchedule >= %@ )", dateObj.startOfDay)
```

In that way you are removing the time part and filtering by the beginning of the day

Comment: i got your idea about the conversion of date sting to date format but issue is when i save date in coredata it contains a datetime. That datetime is different when i fetch the data and due to that difference in time predicate is actually not working .

Answer (score 0):

I would have formatted the dates this way:

```
let dateFormatter = Dateformatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
```

You can apply this to a date and get it as a string like this:

```
 whatever you are saving it as = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Then you will get a date like this, "Mar 17, 2017".

This way of using the date formatter is very practical in your very situation.

When you are fetching you just do it the same way:

```
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(dateSchedule >= %@ )", fromTextField.text!)
```

but I would advise you to use a UIDatePickerView instead:

```
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(dateSchedule >= %@ ), dateFormatter.string(from: datePickerView.date)")
```